# Place median bar across different groups?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi suppose I have the following dataframe,  order by group then total.

```
library ( ggplot2)
library ( dplyr)
df = read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/1meyd5snt6xo9le/plot.csv?dl=1")
df = df [ order ( df$group, df$total), ]

df$pid = factor ( df$pid, levels= df$pid )

df %>% group_by( group )  %>%
  dplyr::summarise  (
    median = median ( total)
  )

ggplot( df, aes(x=pid, y=total, fill=group)) +
  geom_jitter(aes ( color=group), size=10, alpha=0.9)  +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        axis.text.x=element_blank()
        )

> head ( df, 30  )
   pid total group
13 A13     1   Amy
14 A14     1   Amy
15 A15     1   Amy
16 A16     2   Amy
17 A17     2   Amy
18 A18     2   Amy
19 A19     2   Amy
20 A20     2   Amy
21 A21     7   Amy
22 A22     0 Cindy
23 A23     0 Cindy
24 A24     0 Cindy
25 A25     0 Cindy
26 A26     0 Cindy
27 A27     0 Cindy
28 A28     1 Cindy
29 A29     2 Cindy
30 A30     2 Cindy
31 A31     2 Cindy
32 A32     2 Cindy
33 A33     5 Cindy
34 A34     9 Cindy
35 A35     0  Etsy
36 A36     1  Etsy
37 A37     1  Etsy
38 A38     2  Etsy
39 A39     2  Etsy
40 A40     2  Etsy
41 A41     3  Etsy
42 A42     3  Etsy
```

Below is the plot I generate but I artificially annotated the median line with a blue pen. **The tricky part is not only placing the median in the correct y position by x such that its somewhat in the middle of each group**. Is there way I can add this with ggplot? thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

seems that this is what you want to achieve:

```
# Data sample
pid <- c(paste(rep(c('A', 'B'), each=20), 1:40, sep = ''))
grp <- rep(c('Ann','Beth','Camille','Denice'), each = 10)
val <- rnorm(10, mean=1, sd=.2)
df <- data.frame('Pid' = pid, 
                 'Group' = grp,
                 'Value' = c(val, 2*val, 3*val, -5*val))
# Plotting
require(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(Med = median(Value)) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x=Pid, y=Value, fill=Group)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(color=Group), size=10, alpha=0.9)  +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = Med, color=Group))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by first calculating the the sample in between each group. That way the median bar can be properly placed.

```
sm = df %>% group_by( group )  %>%
  dplyr::summarise  (
    median = median ( total),
    pid = pid[ceiling(n()/2)]
  )


ggplot( df, aes(x=pid, y=total)) +
  geom_jitter(aes ( color=group), size=10, alpha=0.9)  +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        axis.text.x=element_blank()
        ) +   geom_crossbar(data=sm, aes(x=pid, y=median, ymin = median, ymax = median ),
                            size=1,col="blue", width = 2.5)
```